# Grep non capturing group and capturing group in the same regex. Print only the capturing group

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file that contains something like this:

```
VERSION = 1.1.1
version = 1.1.1
VERSION = "1.1.1"
VERSION = '1.1.1"
```

etc

I am trying to grep for the version number, using this:

```
grep -E "(VERSION|version|Version)[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.[0-9,A-Z,a-z]+\.[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)" -oP setup.py
```

This complains that 'conflicting matchers specified'. Presumably because there are two capturing groups. I have tried to make the first group non-capturing: `(?:VERSION|version|Version)`, but this gives the same error. The version with the non-capturing group does work when tested on regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/21Pkp2/1), so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in grep.

Comment: You cannot use `E` (ERE) and `-P` (perl mode) together

Comment: Oh, removing -E results in it no longer erroring, but printing the whole line, instead of just the capture group

Comment: You may just use: `grep -ioP "version\D*\K(\d+\.[\d,A-Z,a-z]+\.[\d,a-z,A-Z]+)" file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `-E` (ERE) and `-P` (perl mode) options together in `gnu grep`. If you are using `gnu grep` then just stick with `-P` and use this command to get all version numbers:

```
grep -ioP "version\D*\K(\d+\.[\d,A-Z,a-z]+\.[\d,a-z,A-Z]+)" file
```

```
1.1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
```

- `-i` is used for ignore case match.
- `\K` is PCRE directive to discard previously matched info